# Magento invoice bundle price including tax

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, tax, bundled-product, bundle

On the invoice that is generated by Magento simple products price displays including the TAX which is correct, but for bundle products the single products price displays exclusive of TAX despite what is set in the admin.

How can I make this display the price inclusive of TAX?

Looking at the code it is currently using
`$price = $order->formatPriceTxt($_item->getPrice());`

Some images to demonstrate the issue more

Order back end

[image: Order back end]

Invoice PDF

[image: Invoice PDF]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `$price = $order->formatPriceTxt($_item->getPrice());`

With `$price = $order->formatPriceTxt($_item->getPriceInclTax());`